# Rect that is different sized than image

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

I wanted to try something new and found [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VO8rTszcW4s&list=PLsk-HSGFjnaH5yghzu7PcOzm9NhsW0Urw&index=1) on the web. I used it and tweaked it a little. My goal is to create a zelda clone, meaning my game will be Tile-Based

Now for the problem.
All my sprites are not in 1:1 Ratio. The rect's size I created is TILESIZE * TILESIZE (=64 height, 64 width).

Now the rect sticks to the top:

[image]

but I need it to stick to the bottom center of my sprite:

[image]

for collision detection.

I tried numerous ways and asked my workmates, but they can't help me either.

```
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.images = []

        def addImage(image):
            self.images.append(load_image(path.join(img_folder, "zelda_green", image)))
            print(self.images[-1].get_size())
            scale = TILESIZE/self.images[-1].get_width()
            #print(tuple([scale*x for x in self.images[-1].get_size()]))
            print(scale)
            self.images[-1] = pg.transform.scale(self.images[-1], tuple([int(scale*x) for x in self.images[-1].get_size()]))

        addImage("walk1.png")
        addImage("walk2.png")
        addImage("walk3.png")
        addImage("walk4.png")
        addImage("walk5.png")
        addImage("walk6.png")
        addImage("walk7.png")
        addImage("walk8.png")
        addImage("walk9.png")
        addImage("walk10.png")

        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = pg.Rect(0, 0, TILESIZE, TILESIZE)
        self.game = game
        self.vel = vec(0,0)
        self.pos = vec(x,y) * TILESIZE
        self.vx, self.vy = 0,0
        self.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.y = y * TILESIZE

    def get_keys(self):
        self.vel = vec(0,0)
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT] or keys[pg.K_a]:
            self.vel.x = -PLAYER_SPEED
        if keys[pg.K_RIGHT] or keys[pg.K_d]:
            self.vel.x = PLAYER_SPEED
        if keys[pg.K_UP] or keys[pg.K_w]:
            self.vel.y = -PLAYER_SPEED
        if keys[pg.K_DOWN] or keys[pg.K_s]:
            self.vel.y = PLAYER_SPEED
        if self.vel.x != 0 and self.vy != 0:
            self.vel.x *= 0.7071
            self.vel.y *= 0.7071

    def move(self, dx=0, dy=0):
        if not self.collide_with_walls(dx, dy):
            self.x += dx
            self.y += dy

    def collide_with_walls(self, dir):     
        if dir == 'x':
            hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False)
            if hits:
                if self.vel.x > 0:
                    self.pos.x = hits[0].rect.left - self.rect.width
                if self.vel.x < 0:
                    self.pos.x = hits[0].rect.right
                self.vel.x = 0
                self.rect.x = self.pos.x
        if dir == 'y':
            hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False)
            if hits:
                if self.vel.y > 0:
                    self.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top - self.rect.height
                if self.vel.y < 0:
                    self.pos.y = hits[0].rect.bottom
                self.vel.y = 0
                self.rect.y = self.pos.y

    def update(self):
        global initTime
        frameTime = time.time() - initTime

        if frameTime >= 0.075:
            initTime = time.time()
            self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.get_keys()
        self.pos += self.vel * self.game.dt
        self.rect.x = self.pos.x
        self.collide_with_walls('x')
        self.rect.y = self.pos.y
        self.collide_with_walls('y')
```

Comment: You did not do this right, which is why you probably saw the message *"Links to pastebin.com must be accompanied by code"* while editing. Give a [mcve] **in text form**.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for editing ^^

Comment: I now edited it, it should contain everythng that´s neccessary I think

Comment: _Now the rect sticks to the top, but I need it to stick to the bottom center of my sprite._: I don't understand that sentence. What exactly is your problem? What's the meaning of _I need it to stick to the bottom center of my sprite_?

Comment: [Imgur](https://imgur.com/a/zAVfuQp) I'm sorry for making it unclear. The rect of my image is my Collision Hitbox. It currently automatically goes to the image coordinates which are in the top left. But I want it to go to center bottom of my picture. I uploaded 2 pictures to Imgur for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can seperate the `Rect` that is used for drawing from the actual collision detection. If you look at the [pygame.sprite.spritecollide()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) function, you can see a parameter called `collided`:

> The collided argument is a callback function used to calculate if two sprites are colliding. it should take two sprites as values, and return a bool value indicating if they are colliding. If collided is not passed, all sprites must have a "rect" value, which is a rectangle of the sprite area, which will be used to calculate the collision.

Pygame already ships with several functions that you can use for collision detection:

> collide_rect, collide_rect_ratio, collide_circle,
>   collide_circle_ratio, collide_mask

`collide_rect` is the default.

You can use `collide_mask` for pixel perfect collision, or you can provide your own function.

If you want to just "move" the `Rect` for collision detection, like you said in your comment, you could give your sprites a second `Rect` that's at the bottom of your image, something like this:

```
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((64, 80))
        self.image.fill((0, 200, 200))

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 64, 64)
        # some drawing for demonstration
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, (255, 0, 0), self.rect, 2)

        self.collision_rect = self.rect.copy()
        self.collision_rect.bottom = self.image.get_rect().bottom
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, (255, 255, 0), self.collision_rect, 2)
```

then create a function to be passed as `collided` argument that uses that new `collision_rect` attribute:

```
def collide_collision_rect(left, right):
    return left.collision_rect.colliderect(right.collision_rect)
```

and when calling `spritecollide`, pass the function as last argument:

```
pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False, collide_collision_rect)
```

You have to make sure all your sprites have a `collision_rect` attribute, or first check if the passed sprites have a `collision_rect` attribute and fall back to `rect` if they don't. Also, when you change the `rect` attribute, make sure to update the `collision_rect` attribute as well.

There are of course other ways to do this; you could also calculate how much bigger the image is than the rect, store that in the sprite, and in the new `collided` callback simply move the sprite's `rect` by that amount. Something like this:

```
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((64, 80))
        self.image.fill((0, 200, 200))

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 64, 64)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, (255, 0, 0), self.rect, 2)

        self.diff = self.image.get_rect().height - self.rect.height

def collide_collision_rect(left, right):
    return left.rect.move(0, left.diff).colliderect(right.rect.move(0, right.diff))
```

Comment: What should I put in place of left and right, or do I have to create those and if so in which class? Also where should I put collide_collision? Outside of any class, inside my player class or the new Sprite class you made?

Comment: @Probastian Put the function somewhere outside of any class. You don't have to put anything in for left and right. You just call `pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False, collide_collision_rect)` instead of `pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False)` and `spritecollide` will call `collide_collision_rect` by itself. I know it's not that easy to get your head around passing function references to other functions at first, but that's how `spritecollide` works

Comment: Ok I wrote this line in my Player class: `self.collision_rect = collide_collision_rect()`

But it resulted in an TypeError: `TypeError: collide_collision_rect() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'left' and 'right'`

Which obviously makes sense, since I didn´t define them but I can´t think of anything that would belong there, so what should I fill it with?

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand my answer. Is there anything I could improve so you understand it? Please take a look at the code in my answer again. There's no need to call collide_collision_rect yourself.

Comment: Since I´m a beginner I´m afraid theres nothing you can do on your side, it seems very professional. I guess it´s just my lack of experience, since I´m only familiar with python since 2 weeks.

Anways, I tried it without calling it but I get this error: `AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'collision_rect'` My current changes are as following:

I made the new class as you suggested, with no changes in it.

I changed my `def collide_with_walls` to use your piece of code:

https://pastebin.com/EQ8jrTC3

Sorry for PasteBin but code was too long :C

Comment: Has someone got an answer please?